# What technology can be used for animating a MIPS Pipeline?

Tags: animation, mips, simulation

For my Computer Architecture class, I have to create an **Animated MIPS Pipeline Simulation** with the colors and everything. Any idea which technology can be used to accomplish this? I can do the coding in several high-level languages but I have no idea how to do the animation (tool, library, templates). The animation must be interactive, the user should be able to enter actual MIPS assembly code, and the simulation demonstrate the path it takes using colors "One color for each type of instruction".

Thanks

**Image:** http://www.utdallas.edu/~cantrell/ee4304/Pipe-data+control.jpg

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/152123/583570

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

Visual MIPS R2000 Processor Simulator - http://jamesgart.com/procsim/

Animated Circuit Simulator - http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~wagner/index_files/ckt_anim/

Comment: I need to do something similar to the first link, and I have no idea how to do those kind of animations. I can't use an already made software, I need to create my own.